# Trying to get an array of values not pointers

Tags: arrays

I've been trying to fill an array of `NSMutableAttributedString` with strings from a `NSMutableAttributedString` variable. But it seems the array has pointers not values because when the variable changes so do all the entries in the array.

I'm adding elements to the array with this statement:

```
mutableRecordsArray.insert(myMutableString, at: iObjNumber)
```

but when the contents of `myMutableString` subsequently change, all the entries in `mutableRecordsArray` change to match the new value. How do I populate the array with different persisting values?

Sorry, I'm using Swift (or trying to).

[Here is a snippet from an Xcode playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3N82.png)

Comment: Which language are you using? Please format your question. Can you provide a minimial code example showcasing your problem?

Comment: OK, I found a solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733375/fill-array-with-objects) which makes sense though it's not the way I imagined arrays to work - from my experience with other languages and Apple arrays being alleged "value types".  But, if I instantiate a new object with each new string and add that to my array, then I get persistent values. To me, it seems like that should be built in to the language but now my code works as I wanted it to.